# Fluid flow velocity differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification, problem-solving

Fluid flows steadily under a constant pressure gradient along a straight tube of circular cross-section of radius $a$. The velocity $v$ of a particle of the fluid is parallel to the axis of the tube and depends only on the distance from the axis. The equation satisfied by $v$ is

$$\frac 1r \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = -k$$

Find the general solution for $v$.

---

Here's what I did:

$$\frac 1r \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = -k$$

$$\int \frac 1r \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) \, \mathrm dr = \int -k \, \mathrm dr$$

Integrate by parts, with

$u = \frac 1r$ and $\mathrm du = -\frac1{r^2} \mathrm dr$

$v = r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}$ and $\mathrm dv = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) \, \mathrm dr$

$$\frac 1r \cdot \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) - \int \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) \cdot \frac{-1}{r^2} \, \mathrm dr = -kr + c$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} - \int - \frac 1r \, \mathrm dv = -kr + c$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} + \frac vr = -kr + c$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} = -kr - \frac vr + c$$

$$v = \int (-kr - \frac vr + c) \, \mathrm dr $$

$$v = - \frac 12 kr^2 - v \ln r + c_1r + c_2$$

$$v + v \ln r = - \frac 12 kr^2 + c_1r + c_2$$

$$v(1 + \ln r) = - \frac 12 kr^2 + c_1r + c_2$$

$$v = - \frac{kr^2 + c_1r + c_2}{1 + \ln r}$$

But apparently this is wrong. The solution was $v(t) = -\frac 14 kr^2 + A \ln r + B$, but I do not understand how this was acquired. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think your error occurs where you state $$- \int{-\frac{1}{r}} d v = \ln r + C$$

Comment: @NambiarM. I think you're right. That would equal $\frac vr + c$, yes?

Comment: I don't think so... That's only valid in the case where $r$ and $v$ are independent, and r can be treated as a constant, but they have some dependency.

Comment: @NambiarM. How would I go about integrating that, then?

Comment: I don't think you need to integrate that at all. I think I've figured it out and I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have $$\frac 1r \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = -k$$

Multiplying both sides by r,

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = -kr$$

Integrating both sides,

This gives  $$\mathrm {d} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = -kr \mathrm dr$$

Integrating,
$$\int \mathrm {d} \big( r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr}\big) = \int-kr \mathrm dr \implies$$

$$ r \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} = -\frac{1}{2} kr^2 +A$$

Dividing by r, 
$$ \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} = -\frac{1}{2} kr +\frac{A}{r}$$

So, $$ \mathrm dv = -\frac{1}{2} kr +\frac{A}{r} {\mathrm dr}$$
and, $$ \int \mathrm dv = \int -\frac{1}{2} kr +\frac{A}{r} {\mathrm dr} \implies$$

$$v(t) = -\frac{1}{4} kr^2 +{A}\ln{r} + B$$ which is the desired answer. So, as you can see, integration by parts was not necessary, though a good insight.